# Filter "get_context_data" using multiple data on a ListView

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

In my **ListView** I would like to filter the data by the current user logged from the context_data in :

**views.py**

```
class DashboardListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
model = Links
template_name = 'dashboard/home.html'
context_object_name ='links_list'
paginate_by = 15

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['dashboard_list']= Dashboard.objects.filter()[:15]
    context['todo_list']= Todo.objects.all().order_by('-pk')[:15]
    context['todo_complete']= Todo.objects.all().count()
    context['PasswordUsername_list']= PasswordUsername.objects.all()
    return context
```

I tried to override with a **query_set** but it does work **only** for the links model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to filter all those queries.

```
context['dashboard_list']= Dashboard.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)[:15]
context['todo_list']= Todo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('-pk')[:15]
```

etc - assuming your models all have a `user` FK field pointing to the User model.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer below it's working but do not forget to add :

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

To your ListView otherwise the first model will still be shown.